# SOFAtoolbox/Matlab How to fix properly dimensions of HRTF-data

Tags: matlab

I am trying to convert 10 impulse responses into a single SOFA format data. I stored the data of the impulse responses in the field named `hrtfData.Data.IR` with dimensions M*N*R (where M is the number of measurements, N is the length of each impulse response, and R is the number of microphones).

When I executed `SOFASave`, I encountered the following error. Upon inspecting the data in `hrtfData.API.Dimensions.Data.IR`, it appeared to be cell-type data with the string 'mRn'. Even after updating it to `hrtfData.API.Dimensions.Data.IR {1} = 'MNR'` to match the dimensions of M*N*R, the error persists. Can you please provide guidance on the correct method for verifying and correcting the dimensions?

CODE:

```
M = 10;
N = 4800;
R = 2;

hrir_matrix = zeros(M, N, R);
%...Manipulation of inserting impulse response data into hrir_matrix for hrtfData.Data.IR...

sourcePosition = zeros(M, 3); # ex: [azimuth(deg), elavation(deg), radius(m)]
%...Manipulation of sourcePosition for hrtfData.SourcePosition...

% Create SOFA structure
hrtfData = SOFAgetConventions('SimpleFreeFieldHRIR');
%Configuration for hrtfData
hrtfData.API.M = M;
hrtfData.API.N = N;
% hrtfData.API.Dimensions.Data.IR{1} = 'MRN';

hrtfData.Data.SamplingRate = 48000;
hrtfData.Data.IR = hrir_matrix;
hrtfData.ListenerPosition = [0, 0, 0];  % 
hrtfData.SourcePosition = sourcePosition;
hrtfData.GLOBAL_History = 'converted by Rei';
% Save SOFAfile
SOFAsave('converted_measured_hrirs.sofa', hrtfData);

Error Message: 
Error: SOFAupdateDimensions (line 125)
Data.IR: dimension could not be matched.

Error: SOFAsave (line 60)
Obj=SOFAupdateDimensions(Obj);

Error: main (line 168)
SOFAsave('converted_measured_hrirs.sofa', hrtfData);
```

When I executed `SOFASave`, I encountered the following error. Upon inspecting the data in `hrtfData.API.Dimensions.Data.IR`, it appeared to be cell-type data with the string 'mRn'. Even after updating it to `hrtfData.API.Dimensions.Data.IR {1} = 'MNR'` to match the dimensions of M*N*R, the error persists.

Comment: Are you using MATLAB or Octave? I suspect Octave as the `#` symbol you use for one comment would not be valid MATLAB syntax. Please delete the tag for the language you're not using as applicable, otherwise you may get answers which are not compatible with the tools you're using